# How to rescale -10..10V to 0..5 V?

Tags: voltage

Gyros with an analog interface represent rotational velocity by a varying DC voltage. The range of my gyro woks from -**10 V DC to +10 V DC.** I need a circuit to convert this range into this range: from **0 v DC to 5 V DC**.

Example:

- Gyro OUTPUT   -9 v DC      Circuit OUTPUT    0.25 v DC.
- Gyro OUTPUT   -8 V DC      Circuit OUTPUT    0.50 v DC
- Gyro OUTPUT   -+5 v DC     Circuit OUTPUT    3.75 V DC
- Gyro OUTPUT   +10 v DC     Circuit OUTPUT    5.00 V DC

How to do it?

Comment: Haven't [you asked the same question today already](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/115502/convert-from-a-specifc-range-to-another-one)?  Besides, this question has come up on this board many times.  So, please make a survey.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0DSZ7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

An op amp circuit with a gain of 0.25 (so the voltage range is reduced from 20 to 5). With this alone you get an output of -2.5 to +2.5 volts. Then use two resistors in a voltage divider to put the + input of the op amp at a fixed 2.5 volts. This shifts the circuit output up to 0 to +5.

Comment: Could you give me the code of the op amp that your are using here? And could you explain me what is "+ power" ?

Comment: Any common op amp will work here. The op amp needs a dual power supply such as +12V and -12V. The "+ power" means your + power supply.